# Is it possible to add listview in custom dialogbox in xamarin

Tags: android, ios, listview, xamarin, dialog

I am creating an app using portable xamarin form cross platform having android and IOS project

I want to add listview in custom dialog box. Is it possible?
If is it possible then please share the solution.

You can see example in below image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I created my base page as Absolute Layout with button. When I press button I push absolute layout PopUpListView on top. Here is the code.
On main page

```
class LoginPage : ContentPage
{
    Button btnLogin;
    AbsoluteLayout layout;

    public LoginPage()
    {
        layout = new AbsoluteLayout
        {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
        };

        BackgroundColor = Color.FromUint(0xFFDBDBDB);

        btnLogin = new Button
        {
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,

            Text = "Press me",
            BackgroundColor = Color.FromUint(0xFF6E932D),
            TextColor = Color.White,
        };
        btnLogin.Clicked += BtnLogin_Clicked;
        layout.Children.Add(btnLogin, new Rectangle(0.5f, 0.1f, 0.25f, 0.25f), AbsoluteLayoutFlags.All);

        Content = layout;
    }
    private void BtnLogin_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        layout.Children.Add(new PopUpListView(), new Rectangle(0, 0, 1, 1), AbsoluteLayoutFlags.All);
    }
}
```

And here is your Popoup

```
public class PopUpListView : AbsoluteLayout
{
    public PopUpListView()
    {            
        BackgroundColor = Color.FromRgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
        var list = new MyListView();
        Children.Add(list, new Rectangle(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f), AbsoluteLayoutFlags.All);
    }
}

class MyListView : ListView
{
    public MyListView()
    {
        BackgroundColor = Color.Black;
        ItemsSource =new string[] {"1 choice", "2 choice", "3 choice" };
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, But I want to open listview  in dialog box. It should look like dialog box. is it possible

Comment: Updated my answer